# ASP.Net WebAPI (4.5.2) cannot find Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actor

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I have created a web api (.Net 4.5.2 ~ just the default one VS2015 gives you) and have added two class libraries that use the Service Fabric assemblies. I have also added these assembly references to my web app, and everything compiles.

When I hit F5, I receive a 'Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.ServiceFabric.Actors' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format' error.

So, everything compiles but I'm not sure what this 'incorrect format' means. Has anyone seen this before?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I imagine there's a bitness problem somewhere - are your class libraries 32-bit or 64-bit? They need to be 64-bit if you're using the Service Fabric programming model.